# Select FROM clause in Jena returning no results

Tags: sparql, jena

We are having trouble reliably issuing sparql queries across multiple graphs using the sparql FROM clause within a Jena dataset.

Here is an example of the issue:

```
final String subject = "http://example.com/ont/breakfast#espresso";
final String graph1  = "http://example.com/ont/breakfast/graph#espresso_definition";
final String graph2  = "http://example.com/ont/breakfast/graph#espresso_decoration";

// Add some triples to graphs within the dataset
Dataset  dataset         = DatasetFactory.create();

Model    modelG1         = dataset.getNamedModel(graph1);
Resource espressoTypeG1  = modelG1.createResource(subject)
                                  .addProperty(RDF.type, OWL.Class);
Resource espressoLabelG1 = modelG1.createResource(subject)
                                  .addProperty(RDFS.label, "Espresso");

Model    modelG2         = dataset.getNamedModel(graph2);
Resource espressoLabelG2 = modelG2.createResource(subject)
                                  .addProperty(RDFS.label, "Black Gold");

// The query to execute - returns no results
String queryString = "select * FROM <" + graph1 + "> FROM <" + graph2 + "> " + 
                     "{ <" + subject + "> ?p ?o }";

// This, however, works:
// String queryString = "select * { graph ?g { <" + subject + "> ?p ?o } }";

// Run the query
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
try (QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, dataset)) {
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution result = results.next();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

A combination of a *values* clause and the *graph* keyword has helped us through most of the scenarios where we need to process multiple graphs in the same query. There are some queries where this gets quite unwieldy or downright inefficient.

What can we do to correctly issue a query across a union of models within a single dataset?

Note that the queries are not known at compile time, so we cannot rely on manually creating unions of *model*s in Java code. Furthermore the data is generally added using a combination of loading from files, sparql update and calls to *dataset.asDatasetGraph().add(...)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handling of `FROM` and `FROM NAMED` depends on whether the `Dataset` implementation used supports it, the default in-memory implementations don't support it by default.

To enforce dataset usage you can use the [`DynamicDatasets`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/core/DynamicDatasets.html) and [`DatasetDescription`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/core/DatasetDescription.html) helper classes to resolve the query specified dataset e.g.

```
Dataset resolvedDataset = 
     DynamicDatasets.dynamicDataset(DatasetDescription.create(query), dataset, false); 

try (QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, resolvedDataset)) {   
    // Normal result processing logic goes here... 
}
```